# Ruby on Rails server running in production mode shouldn't show any error details?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment

I thought I read that when a Ruby on Rails server is running in production mode, it won't say so much about an error (the details, showing the code)... but I just try to run the server using

```
ruby script/server -e production
```

and add a `<%= x %>` with the local variable `x` undefined.  It showed a lot of error details including the code... is there a way to make it look better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what do you want to achieve - you might add general exception catching / rescue_from procedure to the ApplicationController, and there put error logging and redirect to some generic "we're sorry" page.

Comment: I thought there is a general switch that let all error message be "We are experiencing problems -- the error has be logged.  Please check back later." or even just a "500 Server Error" instead of showing code details.